# Web Site Hosting

Tags: infrastructure, recommendations

I am looking for a new company to host several web sites. The plan must include:

-- Sharepoint 2010 Foundation (free version)

-- SQL Server

-- ASP.NET

-- Shopping Cart - Specifically to allow users to make credit card purchases, including subscriptions to the site.

I have been looking, but have not been successful in finding the right company.

Also, my current provider seems to have some email issues with google, I fear their IPs may be blacklisted. Long story short, their email forwarding and lists are hit or miss, and I need reliable email services.

Can anyone recommend a hosting company?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the recommendations. I found ASP Host Portal, http://asphostportal.com/, which offers both reasonable prices for SP 2010 and a Shopping Cart feature.

Answer (score 2):

Some popular choices from the Sharepoint world are fpweb.net and Rackspace.

Answer (score 1):

Try [sharepoint hosting](http://www.portalfronthosting.com) at http://www.PortalFronthosting.com  i host there and very happy

Answer (score 0):

You should try free web hosting services with http://www.cloudappsportal.com. They can fulfill the requirements you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

for sharepoint you can try

to find from microsoft official hosting partner page at hosting.asp.net

I hosted my [sharepoint hosting](https://www.seekdotnet.com/moss-hosting/) with www.seekdotnet.com

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try Godaddy OR hostgator quality hosting services with 24*7 support.